# Converting decimal floating number to binary

Tags: language-agnostic, floating-point, binary, decimal

Can anyone please help me convert number (for example) 143,625 to binary? I've been searching through net for quite a long time but didn't find anything with good explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer part can be done by dividing by 2 repeatedly and keeping track of the remainder:

143 / 2 = 71 remainder 1

71 / 2 = 35 remainder 1

35 / 2 = 17 remainder 1

17 / 2 = 8 remainder 1

8 / 2 = 4 remainder 0

4 / 2 = 2 remainder 0

2 / 2 = 1 remainder 0

1 / 2 = 0 remainder 1

So the integer part is 10001111

For the fractional part, multiply it by 2 repeatedly and look at the integer part of the result:

.625 x 2 = 1.25 - we need the integer part, which is 1 - so far we have 0.1, we then disregard the 1 and look at 0.25

0.25 x 2 = 0.5 - so far we have 0.10, we look at 0.5

0.5 x 2 = 1.0 - we have 0.101, no decimal part so we're good.

The whole number is the integer part + the decimal part, so 10001111.101